# How to add a personalized Facebook like button in a Mailchimp email template

Tags: facebook, email, templates, html-email, mailchimp

[image: http://vishnu18.bugs3.com/mc.jpg]

I would like to achieve the above result in MailChimp but the merge tags(*|FACEBOOK:LIKE|*) used in MailChimp allows for only the default fb button. Is there any way I can achieve the result as in the image above using MailChimp?

My code as of now:

```
![<!-- Facebook Share-->
<td valign="middle" height="35" class="like">
    <a href="*|FACEBOOK:LIKE|*"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Like us on Facebook" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Share</a>
</td>
```

Please let me know about the change to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can... share it, not like it:

```
*|SHARELINK:xxx|*
```

According to documentation:

> Inserts a URL to share your campaign archive where xxx is Facebook or
>   Twitter. This is a great way to create a custom link or button image
>   to share your campaign.

In conjunction with setting up Social Cards you should have any control over what's shared.

- Define Social Cards for you Campaign (so you have any control over
  what's shared). But beware of the pitfalls, test carefully! Read:
  http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/customize-social-cards
- Create an online script that handles the message to be shared. You
  can use the button layout you want and attach a link to your script
  that handles the share. Gives you more control, but possibly you'll have to dive into FB apps to do this.